# jQuery modal auto focus first form field

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, focus, autofocus

I'm having an issue here. When opening the modal on my site I want to focus on the first form field (within the modal).

The site in question is: http://capscihealth.staging.wpengine.com/news-and-blog/

Click the 'Demo' button and it will open the modal.

The code I am using to attempt to focus on the first form field in the modal is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo").on('show.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('#input_1_1').focus();
});
```

});

Seems like that should work just fine, but it's not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I solved it by changing show.modal to modal:open.

Clearly I was not thinking straight.